# I am trying to add a line break in .txt file, but when i use "\n" nothing occurs. How can i add a line break in .txt file? This is my code:

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open("Words.txt", "w")

for i in range(5):

    f.write("s"* i)
    f.write("\n")
f.close()


elice_utils.send_file('words.csv')
```

Comment: You're writing `Words.txt` and sending `words.csv`?

Comment: Some editors may truncate the trailing `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
f = open("Words.txt", "w")

for i in range(5):

    f.write("s" * i)
    f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

**output:**

```
s
ss
sss
ssss
```

Tell me if this is not your expected output.
I will update it

Comment: That is my expected output. However, i just copied your code and ran it on my pc. The output is still (ssssssssss) like this not on top of each other. I am using Notepad. I am not sure what is the issue.

Comment: which python version are you using?